# How does a small range of the dependent variable affects linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear

In my regression model, the dependent variable has just a range of 96-100 with a mean of 99.73. My questions are:

1.) (How) Does this affect the quality of the linear regression model?

2.) What would be a reasonable way to take this into account?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you only *observed* this range, or is the DP *naturally bounded* in this range?

Comment: Also: a mean so close to the upper bound is interesting. Do you have many DV observations of exactly 100? Or is there simply a lot of data between 99.73 and 100?

Comment: Finally (perhaps): what are you interested in? Prediction? Inference? Can you say something about your underlying non-statistical question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stephan. The DV is naturally bounded in a range of [0 ; 100] (%). In my dataset - which contains about 1.000 observations - the DV takes only values in the range of [96-100], whereby many observations are exactly 100 or between 99.73 and 100. I also thought about using the Tobit model, but the results are the same (insignificant and coefficients at 0). Therefore I am asking, if this is just a result of the small range and a mean close to the upper bound or if its the reliable result. I am interested in prediction, like how is the DV affected by some IV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your DV is naturally bounded between 0 and 100, but you have only observed values larger than 96, the lower bound is probably not going to be a problem. (Otherwise I would have looked at a beta regression or similar.)

With a large number of observations at or near 100, it sounds like you might have *inflation* at this point. One simple way of dealing with this is to flip your DV (so you have values between 0 and 4, many zeros, and a mean of 0.27), and then use a zero-inflated model. Since you have continuous data, this should not be something like a ZIP (zero inflated Poisson), but a zero inflated gamma regression would be worth looking at. This will give you sensible predictions (not below zero; unbounded above, though - but you could also look at zero inflated beta regression, I just think that is somewhat less common).

As to how the boundedness and (apparent) inflation affects the quality of your or any other model, that is hard to answer. After all, compared to what? You can't really compare the performance of your model to its performance on unbounded, un-inflated data, and think that any difference is very meaningful...

Comment: Thank you again, Stephan, for your extensive explanation. 

For Stata I can only find documentations containing information about the ZIP model. Do you have any link to a documentation for the zero inflated gamma regression?

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately, I am an inveterate R user with zero Stata experience...

Comment: R would also be great. I am very new to R, but it’s worth to try.

Comment: That is good! There are far more resources and similar on R out there: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=zero+inflated+gamma+regression+r

Comment: Thanks so much!!